# awk syntax error: awk: line 29: syntax error at or near :

Tags: shell, awk

I have written a `awk` script and I keep on getting the following error:

`awk: line 29: syntax error at or near :`

I do not understand why I keep on getting this error.

The script is below(script is large but the error is only at the top section. Just added the script for completeness. A flag has been marked for the line a error).

```
#!/bin/sh

tshark -V -r $1 > .pcap_out1_ver.txt
tshark -r $1 > .pcap_out_summ.txt

awk -F ":" '
BEGIN {
#Packet types and subtypes.
    frame_id[0] = "Association Request";
    frame_id[1] = "Association Response";
    frame_id[2] = "Association Response";
    frame_id[3] = "Reassociation Response";
    frame_id[4] = "Probe Request";
    frame_id[5] = "Probe Response";
    frame_id[6] = "Reserved";
    frame_id[7] = "Reserved";
    frame_id[8] = "Beacon";
    frame_id[9] = "ATIM";
    frame_id[10] = "Disassociation";
    frame_id[11] = "Authentication";
    frame_id[12] = "Deauthentication";
    frame_id[13] = "Action";
    for(x=14; x<24; ++x) {
        frame_id[x] = "Reserved";   
    }
    frame_id[24] = "Block Ack Request";
    frame_id[25] = "Block Ack";
    frame_id[26] = "PS-Poll";
    frame_id[27] = "RTS";     #******Error here****
    frame_id[28] = "CTS";
    frame_id[29] = "ACK";
    frame_id[30] = "CF-end";
    frame_id[31] = "CF-end + CF-ack";
    frame_id[32] = "Data";
    frame_id[33] = "Data + CF-ack";
    frame_id[34] = "Data + CF-poll";
    frame_id[35] = "Data + CF-ack +CF-poll";
    frame_id[36] = "Null";
    frame_id[37] = "CF-ack";
    frame_id[38] = "CF-poll";
    frame_id[39] = "CF-ack + CF-poll";
    frame_id[40] = "QoS data";
    frame_id[41] = "QoS data + CF-ack";
    frame_id[42] = "QoS data + CF-poll";
    frame_id[43] = "QoS data + CF-ack + CF-poll";
    frame_id[44] = "QoS Null";
    frame_id[45] = "Reserved";
    frame_id[46] = "QoS + CF-poll (no data)";
    frame_id[47] = "Qos + CF-ack (no data)";
    packet_type[0] = "Management";
    packet_type[1] = "Control";
    packet_type[2] = "Data";
#Variables for storing stats.
    captured_length = 0;
    for(x=0; x<50; ++x) {
        count[x]=0;
        traffic[x]=0;
    }
#Counter for Epoch Time. Avg data rates.
    next_mark=0;
    j=0;
    first_epoch_time = 0;
    cur_epoch_time = 0;
#Counter for rssi values.
    k=0;
}
{
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $1);
    if($1=="Frame Control") { 
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2);
        intRep = sprintf("%d", "0x" substr($2, 4, 2));
        traffic[intRep] += captured_length;
        count[intRep] += 1;
    } else if($1=="Capture Length") {
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2);
        gsub(/ [^\0]*/,"", $2);
        captured_length = $2;
    } else if($1=="Epoch Time") {
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2);
        gsub(/ [^\0]*/, "", $2);
        if(next_mark<$2) {
            if(next_mark==0) {
                next_mark = $2+60;
                first_epoch_time = $2;
            } else {
                next_mark += 60;
                j++;
            }
            #initialization of array element before using.
            traffic_per_min[j] = 0;
            count_per_min[j] = 0;
            data_rate[j] = 0;
        }
        cur_epoch_time = $2;
        traffic_per_min[j] += captured_length;
        count_per_min[j] += 1;
    } else if($1=="SSI signal") {
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2);
        print "ssi signal"
        if( substr($2, 0, 1) == "-") {
            rssi_v[k] = $2;
            rssi_t[k] = cur_epoch_time;
            print rssi_v[k];
            print rssi_t[k];
            k++;
        }
    } else if($1=="Data Rate") {
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2);
        gsub(/ [^\0]*/, "", $2);
        data_rate_avg[j] += $2;
        data_rate[k] = $2;
    }
}
END {
#   print "Packet Subtype" "No. of Packets" "Amount of traffic"
    for(x=0; x<48; ++x) {
        if(count[x] != 0) {
            print frame_id[x]":"count[x]":"traffic[x];
        }
    }
    print "-----"
    for(x=0; x<=j; ++x) {
        print x traffic_per_min[x]/count_per_min[x];
    }

}
' .pcap_out1_ver.txt > .parsed.txt

awk -F " \t" '
BEGIN {
    for(x=0; x<6; ++x)
        count[6] = 0;
    protocol[0] = "HTTP";
    protocol[1] = "ARP";
    protocol[2] = "SMTP";
    protocol[3] = "DNS";
    protocol[4] = "FTP";
    protocol[5] = "DHCP";
}
{
    if($5==protocol[0]){
        count[0] += 1;
    } else if($5==protocol[1]) {
        count[1] += 1;
    } else if($5==protocol[2]) {
        count[2] += 1;
    } else if($5==protocol[3]) {
        count[3] += 1;
    } else if($5==protocol[4]) {
        count[4] += 1;  
    } else if($5==protocol[5]) {
        count[5] += 1;  
    }
}
END {
    for(x=0; x<6; ++x) {
        print protocol[x]:count[x]
    }
}
' .pcap_out_summ.txt > .app_net.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this line in the END block:

```
print protocol[x]:count[x]
```

It should be replaced with:

```
print protocol[x]":"count[x]
```

Comment: I just missed the colon. Why is this giving wrong line number then?

Comment: It must be the line # of your 2nd awk script.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam - be aware that what you posted was a shell script, not an awk script. Within that shell script you have 2 awk scripts. One of those awk scripts has a syntax error in it and the awk interpreter while parsing that script (the second one in your file) found that syntax error at the line number it told you it found it at OF THAT AWK SCRIPT.

Answer (score 3):

Beside your syntax error, could I make a suggestion or 2 about your awk scripts:

1. Get rid of all those null statements (spurious trailing
   semi-colons).
2. You don't seem to be grasping the power of awks associative arrays. Take your second script for example. It could be re-written as just:

   ```
   awk -F " \t" '
      BEGIN { n=split("HTTP ARP SMTP DNS FTP DHCP",protocol,/ /) }
      { count[$5]++ }
      END { for(x=0;x<n;++x) print protocol[x]":"count[protocol[x]]+0 }
   ' .pcap_out_summ.txt > .app_net.txt
   ```

You might want to take a look at the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins (http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/awkprog3/).

Answer (score 0):

As awk tells you, this line of your *second* `awk` script is wrong:

```
print protocol[x]:count[x]
```

You probably meant to *print* a colon:

```
print protocol[x] ":" count[x]
```